# database unable to take data from crawl.php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, web-crawler

I tried to enter URL and press submit button but the database is not updating in wamp64,
[image: processing]
in this above photo, you can see that it's been processing
[image: updated]
I don't know what's the problem in my code I tried to run online on the server but still, it's not working

```
<div class="alert textGradient fixed-bottom" role="alert">
    <strong></strong>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card text-light">
                <a href="/"><img class="card-img-top" src="assets/images/mrfoxie.png" alt="logo" /></a>
                <form method="post" id="formSubmitUrl">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1" style="color: #f42b03;">@</span></div>
                            <input type="url" class="form-control" name="url" placeholder="Submit URL here..." required aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" name="url" required />
                        </div>
                        <input style="width: 100%;" id="buttonSubmit" class="btn btn-lg" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#formSubmitUrl").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".textGradient").text("Processing Please wait...");
            $("#buttonSubmit").prop('disabled', true);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'crawl.php',
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                success: function() {
                    $("#buttonSubmit").text('disabled', false);
                    $(".textGradient").html("The system has received the url");
                }
            });
        })
    })
</script>
```

here is the screenshots of database which are not been updated by crawl.php
[image: database]
[image: site]
[image: images]

Comment: do you get any javascript errors in the console? What data does your php script actually receive?

Comment: no I didn't check the console and it's just receive url, description and title in using wamp64 to localhost it